# Is there any way to reference React components instead of HTML files in XML when developing a Word add-in?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xml, ms-word, word-addins

I am currently working at a company trying to develop a Word add-in (something like Grammarly) using react. I am having A LOT of trouble with doing the following.The project template that Microsoft has for Word add-ins has a manifest.xml file in which they render all the buttons that your tool section will have (like normal Word has letter size, colour, etc). For add-ins, once a button is pressed, a task-pane pops up on the right of the screen showing related information or options.

Here is a small example of one button in xml format

```xml
<Control xsi:type="Button" id="DefinitionsButton">
    <Label resid="DefinitionsButton.Label"/>
        <Supertip>
            <Title resid="DefinitionsButton.Label"/>
                <Description resid="DefinitionsButton.Tooltip"/>
        </Supertip>
        <Icon>
            <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon1.16x16"/>
            <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon1.32x32"/>
            <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon1.80x80"/>
        </Icon>
        <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
            <TaskpaneId>DefinitionsButton</TaskpaneId>
            <SourceLocation resid="Definitions.Url"/>
        </Action>
</Control>
```

After that, an html file is linked that will appear on the task-pane on the right and show all the relevant information when the button is pressed.

```xml
<bt:Url id="Definitions.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/src/taskpane/definitions.html"/>
```

My biggest problem is: I cannot figure out, to save my life, how do you display a React component on the task-pane on a button click. I do not want html files, I have functional react components and I want to somehow link them to the XML file buttons such that some render on the screen when a specific button is pressed.

I also have an index.tsx (yes, it's in typescript) that basically calls App.tsx when the add-in is initialized. That works if the add-in doesn't have any buttons on the top, but just a task-pane. So if the add-in is just the task pane, the components in App.tsx are normally showed on the right.

```js
import...

initializeIcons();

let isOfficeInitialized = false;

const title = "Contoso Task Pane Add-in";

const render = (Component) => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <AppContainer>
      <ThemeProvider>
        <Component title={title} isOfficeInitialized={isOfficeInitialized} />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </AppContainer>,
    document.getElementById("container")
  );
};

/* Render application after Office initializes */
Office.initialize = () => {
  isOfficeInitialized = true;
  render(App);
};

if ((module as any).hot) {
  (module as any).hot.accept("./components/App", () => {
    const NextApp = require("./components/App").default;
    render(NextApp);
  });
}
```

How do I "bind" the App.tsx or react Components to the XML buttons instead of html files?

Thank you.

Comment: Try a very basic component without JSX first: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html (include it directly in your .html file) next I'd try to *build* the react app before linking to it in Word. A built app is just an index.html with a script.